# sorting elements that aren't in a HTML table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a set of DIVs that are displayed like a table, but aren't in an HTML table.
The structure is like this:

```
   <div id="queryResult" style="display: block;">
   <div class="rRow">
      <div class="rCell4">Job</div>
      <div class="rCell4">Company</div>
      <div class="rCell4">Customer</div>
      <div class="rCell4">Product</div>
      <div class="rCell4">Balance</div>
   </div>
   <div class="rRow">
      <div class="rCell4 editMe">46549</div>
      <div class="hideMe coID">1</div>
      <div class="rCell4 coName">Dry Transload</div>
      <div class="rCell4">XYZ co</div>
      <div class="rCell4">39.100</div>
      <div class="rCell4">26.48550</div>
   </div>
   <div class="rRow">
      <div class="rCell4 editMe">46549</div>
      <div class="hideMe coID">1</div>
      <div class="rCell4 coName">Dry Transload</div>
      <div class="rCell4">MNOP co</div>
      <div class="rCell4">39.100</div>
      <div class="rCell4">26.48550</div>
   </div>   
   <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

When displayed it looks something like this:
[image: display]

So what I want is to be able to sort the columns by clicking on the column header or something. I know there are jQuery/JavaScript libraries out there like sorttable but all the ones I find are expecting a HTML table.

Do I bite the bullet and just switch this over to a table, or is there another reasonable (easier) solution?

Comment: I would put it into a table. That actually is tabular data and exactly what the table element was designed for (unless you need a responsive design that just won't work with a table)

Comment: A simple find and replace script could turn this into a table... Would be easier than writing a custom script to sort these columns with the current DOM setup.

Comment: you can just [].sort() each row by grabbing and comparing a sub-property/cell value, then append each one to the container in a loop: they will be sorted.

Comment: @Robert is right. This is an appropriate place for a table.

Comment: You just have to use jQuery and reorder 'rRow' divs according to the clicked column values in each row; Then append them to the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. I added some class to your html for more control.

HTML:

```
<div id="queryResult" style="display: block;">
   <div class="rRow header">
      <div class="rCell4">Job</div>
      <div class="rCell4">Company</div>
      <div class="rCell4">Customer</div>
      <div class="rCell4">Product</div>
      <div class="rCell4">Balance</div>
   </div>
   <div class="rRow body">
      <div class="rCell4 editMe">46549</div>
      <div class="hideMe coID">1</div>
      <div class="rCell4 coName">VDry Transload</div>
      <div class="rCell4">XYZ co</div>
      <div class="rCell4">38.100</div>
      <div class="rCell4">18.48550</div>
   </div>
   <div class="rRow body">
      <div class="rCell4 editMe">46623</div>
      <div class="hideMe coID">1</div>
      <div class="rCell4 coName">Dry Transload</div>
      <div class="rCell4">MNOP co</div>
      <div class="rCell4">31.100</div>
      <div class="rCell4">29.48550</div>
   </div>
  <div class="rRow body">
      <div class="rCell4 editMe">46145</div>
      <div class="hideMe coID">1</div>
      <div class="rCell4 coName">ADry Transload</div>
      <div class="rCell4">JKH co</div>
      <div class="rCell4">42.100</div>
      <div class="rCell4">16.48550</div>
   </div>
   <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

And here is a jQuery to do sorting:

jQuery:

```
$('.header').children('.rCell4').each(function(index){
  $(this).click(function(){
    var container = $('#queryResult');
    var header = $('.header');
    var cmpCols = [];
    $('.body').each(function(){
      cmpCols.push($(this).children('.rCell4').eq(index));
    });
    for(i=0; i<cmpCols.length-1; i++){
      for(j=i; j<cmpCols.length; j++){
        if(cmpCols[i].text() > cmpCols[j].text()){
          var tmp = cmpCols[i];
          cmpCols[i] = cmpCols[j];
          cmpCols[j] = tmp;
        }
      }
    }
    container.html(header);
    for(i=0; i<cmpCols.length; i++){
      container.append(cmpCols[i].parent());
    }
  });
});
```

[Working jsFiddle Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/mwuprayy/)

Answer (score 0):

If you gave each of your `<div class="rRow">` elements a unique `id`, you could reorder them using jQuery `.insertAfter();`

e.g. for

```
<div class="rRow" id="row1">
      ...
</div>
<div class="rRow" id="row2">
      ...
</div>
```

you use $('#row1').insertAfter('#row2'); to flip the position of the two rows.

Then you just need a function which will read each value in a particular "column" in response to an `onclick` event on the header, get the values in that column, sort them, and reorder the rows.